# how to intergate eventemitter3 in CycleJs

Tags: eventemitter, cyclejs

pixijs use [eventemitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) for handler sprites events. for example

```
sprite.on('mousedown', onDown),
```

i am wondering how to make a driver in order to handlering events listening sprites.can any one show me some point?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a driver specifically for EventEmitter.

Both xstream and rxjs (don't know about the other stream libraries cyclejs supports) support dom events and eventemitter events with the `fromEvent` method. With that you can build streams that emit values when the event triggers on the specified target.

check out the [xstream documentation](https://github.com/staltz/xstream/blob/master/EXTRA_DOCS.md#fromEvent) for an example, rxjs is no different.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mouseDown$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  sprite.on('mousedown', e => observer.onNext(e));

  return () => {
    //unsubscribe event here
  }
})
```

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md